# How to prevent angular application making a api call twice when the second call is not appearing on the network?

Tags: angular, observable

I am calling one api in angular to save the data to backend but sometimes data is getting saved twice but in network tab it shows the api is called only once. What can be the issue I am using post method to save the data and it is an observable even user will not be able to make a second call untill first one is completed and even if he tries to hit api twice it shows on network tab that we have called the api twice but in normal case when we are calling api only once that time data is getting saved twice sometimes only.
Any solution for this please I am trying to resolve this issue but not able to find the actual cause.

Comment: Can you please add some relevant code to your question?

Comment: Apart from code need the logs from network and how you are deciding that the api is called twice.

Comment: this.myBookingService.saveBookings(myData).subscribe(response => { });     and this I am calling in my component when user clicks on save button there no way to call this twice till 3-4 seconds because I am showing a loader in whole screen that disables the click on any button

Comment: I was able to find the duplicate issue from db on db it is stroing twice someitimes and time gap between duplicate shipment lies between 1-2 sec since I dont have access of db code I cant share that code. Do you guys think it can be because of preflight request ?

Comment: this code is from the service file for calling the post api saveBookings(inputData: object): Observable<any> {
        return this.apiService.postRecord('bookings', inputData, this.ServerResponseTimeout);
    }

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.